# Is there a way to make a generic AttributeConverter in Micronaut Data?

Tags: java, kotlin, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have a lot of value objects that basically represent UUIDs as the primary identifier of the entity / aggregate:

```
@Singleton
class FooIdConverter : AttributeConverter<FooId, UUID> {
    override fun convertToPersistedValue(
        @Nullable entityValue: FooId?, @NonNull context: ConversionContext
    ): UUID? {
        return entityValue?.id
    }

    override fun convertToEntityValue(
        persistedValue: UUID?, context: ConversionContext
    ): FooId? {
        return if (persistedValue == null) null else FooId(persistedValue)
    }
}

@TypeDef(type = DataType.UUID, converter = FooIdConverter::class)
data class FooId(val id: UUID)
```

Of course, I could copy the converter for every other ID value object (`BarIdConverter`, `FooBarIdConverter`, ...) but this does not seem to be really DRY.

Is there a better way to do this in Kotlin?

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
abstract class EntityId(open val id: UUID)

fun <Id : EntityId> createConverterFor(clazz: KClass<Id>): KClass<out AttributeConverter<Id, UUID>> {
    return object : AttributeConverter<Id, UUID> {
        override fun convertToPersistedValue(entityValue: Id?, context: ConversionContext): UUID? {
            return entityValue?.id
        }

        override fun convertToEntityValue(persistedValue: UUID?, context: ConversionContext): Id? {
            return if (persistedValue == null) null else clazz.primaryConstructor!!.call(
                persistedValue
            )
        }
    }::class
}

val ProjectIdConverter = createConverterFor(FooId::class)

@TypeDef(type = DataType.UUID, converter = ProjectIdConverter)
data class FooId(override val id: UUID) : EntityId(id)
```

**// EDIT (Solution):**

Thanks to @Denis, I have now two solutions. The first and most straight forward:

```kotlin
@Singleton
class EntityIdConverter() : AttributeConverter<EntityId, UUID> {
    override fun convertToPersistedValue(
        @Nullable entityValue: EntityId?, @NonNull context: ConversionContext
    ): UUID? {
        return entityValue?.id
    }

    override fun convertToEntityValue(
        persistedValue: UUID?, context: ConversionContext
    ): EntityId? {
        val ctx = context as ArgumentConversionContext<*>
        return if (persistedValue == null) {
            null
        } else {
            ctx.argument.type.getDeclaredConstructor(UUID::class.java)
                .newInstance(persistedValue) as EntityId
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@TypeDef(type = DataType.UUID, converter = EntityIdConverter::class)
abstract class EntityId(open val id: UUID)
```

```kotlin
data class ProjectId(override val id: UUID) : EntityId(id)
```

The second option is to use KSP and generate the `AttributeConverter`. This option is described in an answer by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a shared converted and recognize the required type using the context which should be of type `ArgumentConversionContext` and `getArgument` will return the type.

Answer (score 0):

I now solved it by generating the converter implementations using KSP following [this](https://proandroiddev.com/so-how-do-i-write-a-kotlin-symbol-processor-ksp-b9606e9e3818) excellent article.

The code generator looks something like this:

```kotlin
override fun process(resolver: Resolver): List<KSAnnotated> {
    val symbols = resolver.getSymbolsWithAnnotation("package.of.annotation")
        .filterIsInstance<KSClassDeclaration>()

    if (!symbols.iterator().hasNext()) {
        return emptyList()
    }

    symbols.forEach {
        val file: OutputStream = codeGenerator.createNewFile(
            dependencies = Dependencies(false, it.containingFile!!),
            packageName = it.packageName.asString(),
            fileName = "${it.simpleName.asString()}Converter"
        )
        file += "package ${it.packageName.asString()}\n"
        val name = it.simpleName.asString()
        file += """
            import io.micronaut.core.annotation.NonNull
            import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Nullable
            import io.micronaut.core.convert.ConversionContext
            import io.micronaut.data.model.runtime.convert.AttributeConverter
            import java.util.*
            
            class ${name}Converter : AttributeConverter<$name, UUID> {
                override fun convertToPersistedValue(
                    @Nullable entityValue: $name?,
                    @NonNull context: ConversionContext
                ): UUID? {
                    return entityValue?.id
                }

                override fun convertToEntityValue(persistedValue: UUID?, context: ConversionContext): $name? {
                    return if (persistedValue == null) null else $name(persistedValue)
                }
            }
        """.trimIndent()
        file.close()
    }

    return symbols.filterNot { it.validate() }.toList()
}
```

And my value objects look like this:

```kotlin
@ValueId
@TypeDef(type = DataType.UUID, converter = ProjectIdConverter::class)
data class ProjectId(val id: UUID)
```